# Redstone Producer/Receiver

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

In Minecraft Pocket Edition, there was recently a new update including basic redstone contraptions. I have experimented around, but I can't find:

- What a Tripwire Hook does, and how it produces redstone currents,
- What a Note Block is, and where it is in Inventory
- What an Activator Rail is used for, and
- How Levers work

  - I know that you touch the lever and it works like a lightswitch, but does it produce its own current like this: =/--() or does it need to process current like this: []---=/---() ([] is producer, - is wire, =/ is lever, () is receiver)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming they work the same way on pocket as they do on PC:

A pair of [Tripwire Hooks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tripwire_Hook) need to be used with String in your hand to set it up, then if someone walks over the string it'll produce redstone current.  They can also be used to craft Trapped Chests if those are on Pocket yet, which produce redstone current when opened.

The [Note Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Note_Block) can be customized to produce notes of different pitches and plays the note when the incoming current switches from off to on. To place the note block in creative mode, it's on the third tab (the one with the bookshelf), and it's the second item on the 4th row in (I have 18 items in a row). It looks like it's a box with a brown and black checkerboard on it.

Levers produce their own redstone current when on, and don't need an exterior power source.

An [Activator Rail](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Activator_rail) modifies the function of minecarts driven over it.

Comment: Will accept in 2 mintes. Do you know where in Inventory the note block is?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I edited the item to note where in the creative inventory the note block is located.